# Export files by SSIS to sharepoint (UNC) - Access is denied

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis

I am trying to export files by SSIS to sharepoint. 
I have create package that is working on my computer. When I upload it on the SQL Server (SSIDB database) and try to run from SSISDB catalog I got error "Access is denied". I have log in to SQL Server by Windows Authentication and my username. 
I have also log in to the database server (with my username) and try to create file in sharepoint directory and I have done that without an error. I can do that also by CMD script from server but when I try run this script in  SSIS package  deployed to SSMS I got an error "Access is denied".
My UNC directory looks like:
\sharepoint@SSL\DavWWWRoot\YYY

Regards
Piotr

Comment: Just for testing, if you change SQL Server service account to your Windows ID, then run the package. see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Give the SQL Server Agent account (or whatever account you are running the job step as) the same permissions your account has in the sharepoint directory.